# Understanding WordPress child theme custom JS loading

Tags: php, functions, theme-development, javascript, child-theme

After hours and hours of trying i can't get my head around it, I'm trying to `wp_enqueue_script` my custom js but WordPress is always looking for it in the parent theme folder, here is what i have tried lately without any success.

My parent theme is Twentysixteen,

Directly `wp_enqueue_script`:

```
function assets() {
         wp_enqueue_script('ajax_filter', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-filter-posts.js', ['jquery'], null, true);
         wp_localize_script( 'ajax_filter', 'mdu', array(
             'nonce'    => wp_create_nonce( 'mdu' ),
             'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
         ));
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'assets', 100 );
```

Register the `wp_register_script` before `wp_enqueue_script`:

```
 function assets() {
     wp_register_script('ajax_filter', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-filter-posts.js', ['jquery'], null, true);
     wp_enqueue_script('ajax_filter');
     wp_localize_script( 'ajax_filter', 'mdu', array(
         'nonce'    => wp_create_nonce( 'mdu' ),
         'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
     ));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'assets', 100 );
```

And also this solution, where I `wp_deregister_script` the parent theme scripts,

```
function assets() {
     wp_deregister_script('parent-script-handle');
     wp_register_script('ajax_filter', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-filter-posts.js', ['jquery'], null, true);
     wp_enqueue_script('ajax_filter');
     wp_localize_script( 'ajax_filter', 'mdu', array(
         'nonce'    => wp_create_nonce( 'mdu' ),
         'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
     ));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'assets', 100 );
```

And i'm following up the recommandations form WordPress:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#enqueueing-styles-and-scripts

**EDIT: fixed some coding errors**
Here is my full functions.php content

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Functions and definitions.
 *
 */

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

            $parent_style = 'twentysixteen-style'; // This is 'twentysixteen-style' for the Twenty Sixteen theme.

                wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
                wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
                                get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
                                        array( $parent_style ),
                                                wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
                                                    );
}


//enqueue and localizing the Javascript.
 function assets() {
     //wp_deregister_script('parent-script-handle');
     wp_register_script('ajax_filter', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-filter-posts.js', ['jquery'], null, true);
     wp_enqueue_script('ajax_filter');
     wp_localize_script( 'ajax_filter', 'mdu', array(
         'nonce'    => wp_create_nonce( 'mdu' ),
         'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
     ));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'assets', 100 );
```

Finally here is the error in my console:

GET http://192.168.33.10/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/js/ajax-filter-posts.js?ver=4.7.2 404 (Not Found)

My JS files is in the twentysixteen-child/js/ folder.

I'm really confused on how this work, and what i'm doing wrong to have this js not being loaded and WP pointing to the parent theme…

Thanks for any help and clarification !

kindly.

Matth.

Comment: I hope your child theme is activated and function.php listed above is in /twentysixteen-child/function.php

Comment: @KAGGDesign, I confirm this is the case, and if my understanding is correct I wouldn't have the error message in the console if the theme was not activated and as well as the functions.php not set at the proper place.

Comment: BTW, you have some errors in code, but they should not affect.

1. $parent_style = 'twentysixteen-style'; // as your theme uses it

2. wp_deregister_script('parent-script-handle'); // has no effect. no such script 'parent-script-handle' exists in twentysixteen theme

3. in add_action priority 100 has no effect in your case

Comment: Ah ok, didn't got that i though it was a generic string to call the parents styles and scripts… 
Fixing this now.

Comment: The problem could be in caching. Your code

    wp_register_script('ajax_filter', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-filter-posts.js', ['jquery'], null, true);

uses null as 4th parameter. In this case, WP does not add any version number to the end of js path. However, in your console we see `?ver=4.7.2`

Try to register script with default parameters, like that:

    wp_register_script('ajax_filter', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-filter-posts.js', ['jquery']);

Comment: Just tried with the default parameter


     `wp_register_script('ajax_filter', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-filter-posts.js', ['jquery']);`

and also by adding a version number

    `wp_register_script('ajax_filter', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-filter-posts.js', ['jquery'], '1.0', false);`

And i got the exact same error message, still with word press version showing up


     `GET http://192.168.33.10/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/js/ajax-filter-posts.js?ver=4.7.2 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: it seems you have the same code in parent theme: /twentysixteen/functions.php  This is the only explanation why get_stylesheet_directory_uri() returns `/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen` but not `/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen-child`

Comment: ok, let me look at this more closely, i'll have a look at the `wp_scripts` to get a better understanding on what's going here and i'll get back here afterwards. thanks for the help !

Comment: i found my issue i was modifying the wrong files… (hitting my head on the wall) playing with `echo` in to identify that.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, you can add your comment as an answer so i can set it as accepted answer.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the proper way to load a custom javascript in your child theme, `wp_localize_script` is only necessary if you need to exchange data between JS and PHP (Client and server).

```
function assets() {
     wp_register_script('ajax_filter', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-filter-posts.js', ['jquery'], '1.0', false);
     wp_enqueue_script('ajax_filter');
     wp_localize_script( 'ajax_filter', 'mdu', array(
         'nonce'    => wp_create_nonce( 'mdu' ),
         'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
     ));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'assets');
```

So my issue as noticed by @KAGG was that i was loading this JS from another file…

Thanks for his help !

Matth

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have the same code in parent theme: `/twentysixteen/functions.php` This is the only explanation why `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` returns `/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen` but not `/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen-child`